# Como dá um loop infinito

Tags: php, loop

Como faço para tratar a exceção abaixo:

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ...`

Comment: De que maneira o tag `php` está relacionado com esta pergunta? Pode explicar melhor o que pretende?

Comment: estou dando um `for` com php!

Comment: Está a usar ajax? quer que a página fique bloqueada? qual é a intenção? que situação quer dar ao utilizador?

Comment: Editei para melhor entendimento desculpe a ignorância da minha parte com relação a tecnologia!

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que trava o navegador?

Comment: Você não deve tratar exceção alguma. Se você sabe que há um *loop* infinito mesmo, você deve achar um meio dele terminar. Como você não colocou código algum, não temos como ajudar.

Comment: Havia pessoas votando que a pergunta não estava clara, como você aceitou uma resposta que não resolve o problema descrito, sou obrigado a concordar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso usando a função [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php) do PHP. Apenas passe o tempo limite de execução de um script, em segundos.

Isso não tem nada a ver com o browser. O bloqueio não acontece lá, mas sim no seu servidor. O tempo limite padrão é de 30 segundos. Quando ele é ultrapassado, acontece esse erro. Alternativamente, você pode alterar o "max_execution_time" no php.ini.

Comment: Se há um *loop* infinito, você pode colocar o limite para 1 milhão que não vai resolver.

Comment: O que eu entendi é que a pergunta foi como fazer com que a execução do script não fosse interrompida em 30 segundos. Para isso, aí está a resposta. Se o objetivo for resolver o problema do loop, aí só vendo o código para ver qual é a causa do loop.

Comment: O título é bem claro que há um *loop* infinito. Se você estiver certo, a pergunta está errada e você deu um chute. O ideal é só responder o que está claro, o que é certo. Você está correndo o risco de receber negativos.

Comment: Eu não questionei a existência do loop infinito. Também acho que ela está clara. Acontece que a pergunta foi editada há pouco tempo. Eu não dei um chute. Para aumentar o tempo, o procedimento é esse. A resposta é de acordo com a maneira que a pergunta foi formulada e ela foi editada quando eu respondi. A versão anterior dava a entender que a intenção do autor era aumentar o tempo de execução do script.

Comment: Desde o início a pergunta era sobre *loop* infinito, em nenhum momento a pergunta era ou é sobre aumentar o tempo de execução.

Comment: Eu acho que vocês dois têm razão. A pergunta mudou radicalmente com as duas últimas edições. @bigown